# How to add a custom source to apt repositories?

Tags: linux, apt, repository

I'm trying to add kata-containers repository to my apt sources (fresh debian install) but i keep getting an "unable to locate package x" despite adding the source, key and updating the package manager  :

```
$ ARCH=$(arch)
$ BRANCH="${BRANCH:-master}"
$ sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/katacontainers:/releases:/${ARCH}:/${BRANCH}/xUbuntu_$(lsb_release -rs)/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kata-containers.list"
$ curl -sL  http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/katacontainers:/releases:/${ARCH}:/${BRANCH}/xUbuntu_$(lsb_release -rs)/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo -E apt-get update
$ sudo -E apt-get -y install kata-runtime kata-proxy kata-shim
```

Source : https://github.com/kata-containers/documentation/blob/master/install/ubuntu-installation-guide.md

Inside sources.list.d/kata-containers.list :

```
deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/katacontainers:/releases:/x86_64:/master/Debian_9/ /
```

What did i miss ?

Answer (score 1):

For Debian use ([debian 9 is supported](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/katacontainers:/releases:/x86_64:/master/Debian_9/)):

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARCH=$(arch)
BRANCH="${BRANCH:-master}"
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/katacontainers:/releases:/${ARCH}:/${BRANCH}/Debian_${VERSION_ID}/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kata-containers.list"
curl -sL  http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/katacontainers:/releases:/${ARCH}:/${BRANCH}/Debian_${VERSION_ID}/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo -E apt-get -y install kata-runtime kata-proxy kata-shim
```